# Get/display object and properties from array in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on a project where I'm trying to add a User object to a Logins array with properties that are input by a user.

Once added to the Logins array, I'm trying to display the User object (id, firstName, lastName) in a single list item. Each new User is added next in line on the list.

What I'm trying to do is make each property of the object accessible, in order to do something like validate for multiple IDs/duplicate names by searching through user.id. Right now I've only been able to display from the array that I'm pushing my data to, as three list items.

Is there a way to store my user input so that I could display the User object itself in one list item, rather than (what looks like) three separate pieces of data? Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  ng-app>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

function LoginController($scope) {
    $scope.user = {
        id: "",
        firstName: "",
        lastName: ""
    };
    $scope.logins = [];
    $scope.login = function () {
        $scope.logins.push($scope.user.id, $scope.user.firstName, $scope.user.lastName);
        console.log($scope.logins);

    };

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-app ng-controller="LoginController">
    <div>Hello {{ user.firstName }}</div>
    <input ng-model="user.id"></input>
    <input ng-model="user.firstName"></input>
    <input ng-model="user.lastName"></input>

    <input type="submit" ng-click="login()" value="Login"></input>
    <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="login in logins">{{ login }}</li>
    </ul>    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want `logins` to be an array of users (which should thus be named `users`). So replace

```
$scope.logins.push($scope.user.id, $scope.user.firstName, $scope.user.lastName);
```

by

```
$scope.logins.push($scope.user);
```

I guess you also want the currently edited user to be a new empty user once the previously edited one has been added to the array, so add

```
$scope.user = {
    id: "",
    firstName: "",
    lastName: ""
};
```

Comment: This works! not sure why I thought I needed to push all that. How would I go about displaying the data in string format?

Comment: {{ user.id }} - {{ user.firstName }} {{ user.lastName }} (for example)